# Magento2 Add Product Attribute Not Working

Tags: attributes, product, magento2

I have created a file **setup/installdata.php**:

```
    use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
    use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

    class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
    {
        private $eavSetupFactory;

        public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
        {
            $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        }

        public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                'name',
                [
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'backend' => '',
                    'frontend' => '',
                    'label' => 'attrlabel',
                    'input' => 'select',
                    'class' => '',
                    'source' => 'a\b\Model\Attribute\Source\m',
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'required' => false,
                    'user_defined' => true,
                    'default' => '',
                    'searchable' => false,
                    'filterable' => false,
                    'comparable' => false,
                    'visible_on_front' => false,
                    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                    'unique' => false,
                    'apply_to' => '',
                    'attribute_set' => 'Default',
                ]
            );
        }
    }
```

Then, in **etc/module.xml**, I have:

```
    <module name="Conlabz_IdentityCheck" setup_version="1.0.0" />
```

But I still don't see the attribute created.

I also tried the following:

In the Magento root folder, I run the following commands:

```
    php bin/magento module:disable
    php bin/magento module:enable
    php bin/magento setup:upgrade
    php bin/magento cache:flush
```

All succeed without an error, but as I said, it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check your filename **setup/installData.php**.

"D" should be capital.

Then search table "setup_module" in your magento2 database and delete entry for "Conlabz_IdentityCheck".

**Then run following command :**

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Answer (score 0):

1. First, the file and folder name should be Setup/InstallData.php
2. In your InstallData.php file, you have to add this code at the first line:

   namespace Conlabz\IdentityCheck\Setup;

Then just run the CLI commands.

However, if you still facing issues then for reference you can checkout this guide on [Magento Attributes](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/configuring-product-attribute-sets-in-magento/).